# Use iPad socket adapter with MacBook Pro charger

Tags: macbook-pro, ipad, charger

I have an iPad. Can I use its socket adapter (the part of the charger the connects to the socket) in my MacBook Pro charger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

The socket adapter of iPad and Macbook Pro have the same standard**:(2.5A 250V~)**.
So they are interchangeable.

Comment: is the only difference the time of charging? I believe the iPad chargers ar 10W and the new Macbook pro chargers are 61W. How much of a performance difference will this make? Thx.